# Converting permutation tree into English prose

Tags: c#, combinations

I'm designing a software that reads numerical values entered by the user. It then generates sentences that are used in medical reports. A bit of complication arises due to the fact that there are so many variances between the sentences and to create a setnence for each type of variance is excruciatingly long and probably unproductive.

Let me give an example to which I am struggling with:

Let's say that the diagnoses relies on the human nerves.

Consider the following nerves: median, ulnar, radial.

Now, lets say a user entered numerical values into the software which generates what nerves are abnormal.

Consider the following statements:

Indidcation of neuropathy to the left median nerve.

Indication of neuropathy of the bilateral ulnar nerve.

Indication of neuropathy of the right radial nerve.

Each statement is produced by a set of statements and it is possible to combine these statements to have each variant. Variant being -

Left(L), Right(R), Bilateral (B) - and median, ulnar, and radial.

So the variance would be 3^3 = 27.

However, when there are more nerves, the variance rises expponentially. If I have 5 nerves, then it would be 3^5.

The question is: How can design the software so it produces the following sentence:

Indication of neuropathy of the left median, bilateral ulnar, and right radial nerve, without actually having every combination of these statements and every conditional statement for each one.

It would need to work for a variety of statements: To give an example of the sentence variance:

Decreased nerve conduction velocity of the left tibial nerve.

Decreased nerve conduction velocity of the left peroneal nerve.

Combine - Decreased nerve conduction velocity of the left tibial and peroneal nerve.

To summarize: The software would produce a variety of these types of sentences: user selects appropriate similar sentences and the program combines them.

Comment: So... which part of this are you having trouble with? It's pretty straightforward, just combine the parts with a comma, prepend `and ` to the last one if more than one, and voilà...

Comment: what if you have: left median, right ulnar, and left radial. How would i make it so that its left median, radial and right ulnar.

Comment: The first one should probably be an `and` as opposed to a comma. Anyway, why do you have it in string form? How did you build that string? Could you please show your current code?

Comment: Each statement shown would be individualized that results from the user entered numerical value.

Comment: Your title said nothing at all about your problem.  I've changed it to something that attempts to describe the issue; feel free to adjust it further.

Comment: Basically, the code would need to recognize which sentences I would like to combine and concatinate it and place it together with the right wording and grammar.

Answer (score 0):

You could have collections for each possible diagnosis and then add nerves (?Strings) to them as you calculate issues. Then for each diagnosis you would produce a sentence by iterating through the matching collection and combining each nerve into a representative statement (" Decreased nerve conduction velocity of the **left tibial and peroneal nerve**"). This would probably be my approach.

You could also do the opposite approach and have a Nerve class, with properties for each diagnosis. You could modify these properties and then iterate through the different diagnosis's and search for nerves which have certain properties, although this seems slower (double iteration).

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar a couple years ago to save some users some time from typing repetative text over and over.  I created a series of checkboxes that the user would check that would load text from a datasource (sql?) concatinate them together into a textbox.  This would allow the user to edit the text to make sure it's readable and has their own spin on it, but automatically inserting templated text would save time typing it.  They had different categories, so i added a combobox that changed the set of checkboxes.

so you could have:
Body part (dropdown): Arm, Leg
When user selects "Arm", a list of fingers, wrist, elbow, etc. appear.
When "Leg" is selected, it hides the arm's checkboxes, then shows leg's: knees, heel, etc.

unchecking the box would find the text in the textbox and remove it.

I also created another one that was more like a grid, and the user would click "Add Row" to add more rows. Each row would have a series of comboboxes that theyw oudl first select the category, then maybe a subcategory, then finally the name of the templated item, "bilateral ulnar nerve" for example.

Hope this helps - i can provide sample code depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need some conditions, but ideally, you want to use some sort of templates.  A simple template approach is String.Format().  For example:

```
String.Format("{0} {1}.", getSymptom(userSymptomNumber), getLocation(userLocationNumber));
```

In this extremely simple scenario, getSymptom would return "Indidcation of neuropathy to the" and getLocation would return "left median nerve" from some sort of data store.  More complicated templates could allow the inclusion of collections.  You should look at some of the C# template engines that are available, or you can roll your own lightweight templating code similar to String.Format.  Your core conditionals will decide how you sentences are formed.  From there, it is just filling in the variations with the user input.  You should not right out thousands of complete sentences.